# How can i fix errors with pulp Value Error: too many values to unpack?

Tags: pip, valueerror, nameerror, pulp, modulenotfounderror

I need help with this homework. i just can't find the error. please help me

A company produces five different types of beer and wants to maximise the possible contribution margin by optimising the production quantities. The contribution margin that can be achieved by the different types of beer is shown in the following table:
Variety DB per litre

A 1,9 €
B 1,9 €
C 1,8 €
D 1,4 €
E 1,8 €

The table below shows both the filling time (AD) and the raw material consumption (RV) for one litre of the respective beer varieties:

Variety AD RV1 RV2 RV3

A 2 1,3 1,65 1

B 1,45 1,8 1 1

C 1,2 1,55 1,3 1,4

D 1 1,2 2,1 1,5

E 1,75 1 1 1,55

The filling of the different varieties takes place on the same equipment. Theoretically, a daily bottling quantity of 4000 l of beer type A is possible while maintaining the time capacity, if no other type is produced. The daily supply of raw materials 1, 2 and 3 is as follows:
Raw material units

1 7400

2 7100

3 5900

The maximum daily demand for the products is constant and only differs between the different varieties. The maximum demand for each variety is shown in the table below:

Variety max. demand

A 2100 l

B 950 l

C 1100 l

D 1500 l

E 1550 l

Since the beer types B and C as well as the types A and D each address the same target group, a maximum of 1400 l of B and C or 2700 l of A and D should be produced in total in order to reduce the entrepreneurial risk due to a drop in sales.

Task: Describe the production problem using a linear optimisation model and determine the optimal daily production quantities of the individual beer types.

```
!pip install pulp 
import pulp
solver_list = pulp.listSolvers(onlyAvailable=True) 
print(solver_list)

lp_problem = pulp.LpProblem("LPProblem", pulp.LpMaximize)
x1 = pulp.LpVariable('x1', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x2 = pulp.LpVariable('x2', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x3 = pulp.LpVariable('x3', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x4 = pulp.LpVariable('x4', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x5 = pulp.LpVariable('x5', lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

lp_problem += 1,9 * x1 + 1,9 * x2 + 1,8 * x3 + 1,4 * x4 + 1,8 * x5, "Z"

lp_problem += 2 * x1 <= 4000

lp_problem += 1,3 * x1 + 1,8 * x2 + 1,55 * x3 + 1,2 * x4 + 1 * x5 <= 7400
lp_problem += 1,65 * x1 + 1 * x2 + 1,3 * x3 + 2,1 * x4 + 1 * x5 <= 7100
lp_problem += 1 * x1 + 1 * x2 + 1,4 * x3 + 1,5 * x4 + 1,55 * x5 <= 5900

lp_problem += x1 <= 2100
lp_problem += x2 <= 950
lp_problem += x3 <= 1100
lp_problem += x4 <= 1500
lp_problem += x5 <= 1550
lp_problem += x1 + x4 <= 2700
lp_problem += x2 + x3 <= 1400

print(lp_problem)

lp_problem.solve()
print("Status:", pulp.LpStatus[lp_problem.status])

for variable in lp_problem.variables():
print("{} = {}".format(variable.name, variable.varValue))

print("Deckungsbeitrag =",pulp.value(lp_problem.objective))
```

[Error Message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71ClU.png)

Comment: Python, like most programming languages, uses dots and not commas to separate decimals.